# Parsing an XML file using nokogiri to create \index fields for LaTeX

Tags: ruby, latex, nokogiri

I'm a professional indexer new to Ruby and nokogiri and I am in need of some assistance.

I'm working on a set of macros that will allow me to take an XML file, output from my indexing software, and parse it into valid `\index{}` commands for inclusion in a LaTeX source file. Each XML `<record>` contains at least two `<field>` tags, so I will have to iterate over the multiple `<field>` tags to build my `\index{}` entry.

The following is an example of an index record from the xml file.

```
<record time="2022-08-27T17:25:12" id="30">
    <field><text style="i"/><hide>SS </hide>Titanic<text/></field>
    <field>passengers</field>
    <field class="locator"><text style="b"/>5<text/></field>
</record>
```

I will produce intermediate output of this record in the form of:

```
\index{Titanic@\textit{SS Titanic}!passengers|textbf} 5
```

(The numeric locator is used to place the `\index{}` entry at the correct spot in the LaTex file and won't be included in the LaTeX source file)

I am using nokogiri to manipulate the xml file and have been able to reach the point where I return a nodelist that contains just the `<field>` tags for each `<record>`, but I need to be able to retrieve all the text in the `<field>`, including the formatting information (if I use the `text` method on a `<field>`, it returns "SS Titanic" for example, with all formatting information stripped away).

I'm stuck on how to access the entire text string in the `<field>` tag. Once I can get that, I have a good idea of how to structure my parser.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this help?

```rb
xml = "<record time="2022-08-27T17:25:12" id="30">
    <field><text style="i"/><hide>SS </hide>Titanic<text/></field>
    <field>passengers</field>
    <field class="locator"><text style="b"/>5<text/></field>
</record>"

fields = Nokogiri::XML(xml).xpath(".//field")

puts fields.first.text  #=> "SS Titanic"
puts fields.map(&:text) #=> ["SS Titanic", "passengers", "5"]
```

Comment: That does help, thanks.

In doing some further investigation, I found the method to_s returns the complete text of the field. Combining that with map will give me all the information I need to pass to my parser.